# nginx path rewrite

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

What I'm getting is:

```
/index.php/rest/item/1
```

However, it should be going to:

```
/rest/item/1
```

How can I rewrite every request from /index.php/rest/ to /rest/ ?

Thanks!

**Edit:**
It seems to only work if I make it a redirect:

```
rewrite ^/index.php/rest/(.*)$ /rest/$1 permanent;
```

If I use "break" or "last" it 404's on me, any idea? I'm using Gallery3, which is written on php's Konoha framework.

Answer (score 2):

I've worked with Dmitry the past few weeks on solving this and we finally found out what the problem was. I just needed it it make sure that it doesn't finish when processing the rule. Removing the "last" or "break" from the rule fixes it:

```
if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/index.php/rest/(.*)$ /rest/$1;
        rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php?kohana_uri=$1 last;
}
```